# Calculating value of formula

Tags: vba, replace, equation, evaluate

Is there a way to read a formula into VBA with the structure "y=3x^2-5*x+3" and have the "y="  be replaced by a blank ("") and the x replaced by an actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EVALUATE` to caculate a string formula

If you had `3*x^2-5*x+3` (rather than `3x^2-5*x+3`) then this code retruns 53

```
Dim strIn As String
strIn = "3*x^2-5*x+3"
MsgBox Evaluate(Replace(strIn, "x", "5"))
```